# I Inherited a complicated SSRS report that uses a query to grab information about our projects

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

So I have this query driven ssrs report and I have been asked on part of the report to list the engineers that billed the most hours to the project list them in order from most to least... max to min. This is the huge Query.

```
declare @startDate date
declare @endDate date
set @startDate = GETDATE() -30
set @endDate = GETDATE()
SELECT
        PN_B,
        PN_A,
        Project_Practice,
        Date_Closed_UTC,
        Project_ID,
        Company_Name,
        Invoiced_Service_Amount,
        AGR_Amt,
        Total_Service_Billing,
        Project_TCW,
        Hrs_Budgeted, 
        Est_Hours,
        Billing_Method,
        Project_Total_Hrs,
        Project_Hrs_B,
        Project_Hrs_NB,
        Project_Hrs_NC,
        Project_Hrs_Agr,
        Project_Status,
        Location,
        OPP_RECID,
        Opportunity_RecID, 
        AM,
        DA,
        PM,
        PeopleNRole,
        PM_Billing_Method_ID
    FROM 
    (
     SELECT
     PPRS2.PN_B,
     PPRS2.PN_A,
     PPRS2.Project_Practice,
     PPRS2.Date_Closed_UTC,
     PPRS2.Project_ID,
     PPRS2.Company_Name, 
     PPRS2.Invoiced_Service_Amount,
     PPRS2.AGR_Amt,
     PPRS2.Total_Service_Billing,
     PPRS2.Project_TCW,
     PPRS2.Hrs_Budgeted,
     PPRS2.Est_Hours,
     PPRS2.Billing_Method, 
     PPRS2.Project_Total_Hrs,
     PPRS2.Project_Hrs_B,
     PPRS2.Project_Hrs_NB,
     PPRS2.Project_Hrs_NC,
     PPRS2.Project_Hrs_Agr,
     PPRS2.Project_Status, 
     PPRS2.Location,
     PPRS2.OPP_RECID,
     AMDA2.Opportunity_RecID,
     AMDA2.AM,
     AMDA2.DA,
     AMDA2.PM,
     PeopleNRole,
     PPRS2.PM_BILLING_METHOD_ID
    FROM 
    (
     SELECT
     PN_B,
     PN_A,
     Project_Practice,
     Date_Closed_UTC,
     Project_ID,
     Company_Name,
     Invoiced_Service_Amount,
     AGR_Amt,
     Total_Service_Billing, 
     Project_TCW,
     Hrs_Budgeted,
     Est_Hours,
     Billing_Method,
     Project_Total_Hrs,
     Project_Hrs_B,
     Project_Hrs_NB,
     Project_Hrs_NC,
     Project_Hrs_Agr, 
     Project_Status,
     Location,
     OPP_RECID,
     pl2.PeopleNRole,
     PM_Billing_Method_ID
    FROM
    (
     SELECT
     Table_B.Project_Number AS PN_B,
     Table_A.Project_Number AS PN_A,
     Table_A.Project_Practice,
     Table_A.Date_Closed_UTC, 
     Table_A.Project_ID,
     Table_A.Company_Name,
     Table_A.Invoiced_Service_Amount,
     Table_A.AGR_Amt, 
     Table_A.Total_Service_Billing,
     Table_B.Project_TCW,
     Table_A.Hrs_Budgeted,
     Table_A.Est_Hours,
     Table_A.Billing_Method,
     Table_B.Project_Total_Hrs, 
     Table_B.Project_Hrs_B,
     Table_B.Project_Hrs_NB,
     Table_B.Project_Hrs_NC,
     Table_B.Project_Hrs_Agr,
     Table_A.Project_Status, 
     Table_A.Location,
     Table_A.OPP_RECID,
     Table_A.PM_BILLING_METHOD_ID
    FROM
     (
      SELECT
      Total_Service_Billing,
      AGR_Amt,
      Invoiced_Service_Amount,
      Sales_Tax_Amount_Total,
      Project_Number,
      Project_ID, 
      Date_Closed_UTC,
      Est_Hours,
      Billing_Method,
      Company_Name,
      Project_Status,
      Project_Practice,
      Hrs_Budgeted,
      Location, 
      OPP_RECID,
      PM_Billing_Method_ID
    FROM
    ( 
     SELECT
     Project_Service_Totals.Service_Total AS Total_Service_Billing,
     Project_Service_Totals.AGR_Amt, 
     Project_Service_Totals.Service_Invoice_Amt_Total AS Invoiced_Service_Amount, 
     Project_Service_Totals.Sales_Tax_Amount_Total, 
     Project_Service_Totals.Project_RecID AS Project_Number,
     PM_Project.Project_ID, 
     PM_Project.Date_Closed_UTC,
     PM_Project.Est_Hours,
     PM_Project.PM_Billing_Method_ID AS Billing_Method, /* A = Actual Rates F = Fixed Fee for the Inital Project Type */
     Company.Company_Name, 
     PM_Status.Description AS Project_Status,
     PM_Type.Description AS Project_Practice, 
        SUM(v_rpt_Project.hours_budget) AS Hrs_Budgeted,
        Owner_Level.Description AS Location, 
        PM_Project.Opportunity_RecID AS OPP_RECID,
     PM_Project.PM_Billing_Method_ID
    FROM
    (
     SELECT
        SUM(Service_Invoice_Amt - Sales_Tax) + SUM(BL_AGR_AMT) AS Service_Total, 
        SUM(BL_AGR_AMT) AS AGR_Amt,
        SUM(Service_Invoice_Amt) AS Service_Invoice_Amt_Total,
        SUM(Sales_Tax) AS Sales_Tax_Amount_Total,
        Project_RecID
    FROM
        (
         SELECT        
         Billing_Log_RecID,
         Invoice_Number,
         Invoice_Amount AS Service_Invoice_Amt, 
         PM_Project_RecID AS Project_RecID,
         Sales_Tax_Amount AS Sales_Tax, 
         AGR_Amount AS BL_AGR_AMT
    FROM 
    Billing_Log AS Billing_Log_1
    )
    AS Service_Invoice_Total
        GROUP BY Project_RecID
        ) 
        AS Project_Service_Totals 
         INNER JOIN
            PM_Project
            ON 
            Project_Service_Totals.Project_RecID = PM_Project.PM_Project_RecID 
             INNER JOIN
            Company
            ON
            PM_Project.Company_RecID = Company.Company_RecID
            INNER JOIN
            PM_Status
            ON
            PM_Project.PM_Status_RecID = PM_Status.PM_Status_RecID
            INNER JOIN
            PM_Type
            ON
            PM_Project.PM_Type_RecID = PM_Type.PM_Type_RecID
            INNER JOIN
            v_rpt_Project
            ON
            PM_Project.PM_Project_RecID = v_rpt_Project.ProjectNbr
            INNER JOIN
            Owner_Level
            ON
            PM_Project.Owner_Level_RecID = Owner_Level.Owner_Level_RecID
            GROUP BY 
            Project_Service_Totals.Service_Total,
            Project_Service_Totals.AGR_Amt, 
            Project_Service_Totals.Service_Invoice_Amt_Total,
            Project_Service_Totals.Sales_Tax_Amount_Total, 
            Project_Service_Totals.Project_RecID,
            PM_Project.Project_ID,
            PM_Project.Date_Closed_UTC, 
            PM_Project.Est_Hours,
            PM_Project.PM_Billing_Method_ID,
            Company.Company_Name,
            PM_Status.Description,
            PM_Type.Description, 
            Owner_Level.Description,
            PM_Project.Opportunity_RecID
            )
            AS T
            )
            AS Table_A
            INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT
        Project_Hrs_B,
        Project_Hrs_NB,
        Project_Hrs_NC,
        Project_Total_Hrs,
        Project_Hrs_Agr,
        Project_TCW, 
        Project_Number
        FROM
        (
         SELECT
         SUM(Hrs_Billable) AS Project_Hrs_B,
         SUM(Hrs_NonBillable) AS Project_Hrs_NB, 
         SUM(Hrs_NoCharge) AS Project_Hrs_NC,
         SUM(Hrs_Billable + Hrs_NonBillable + Hrs_NoCharge) AS Project_Total_Hrs,
         SUM(Hrs_Agr) AS Project_Hrs_Agr,
         SUM(Project_TC) AS Project_TCW, 
         Project_Number
        FROM
         (
          SELECT
          SUM(Hrs_B) AS Hrs_Billable,
          SUM(Hrs_NB) AS Hrs_NonBillable,
          SUM(Hrs_NC) AS Hrs_NoCharge,
          SUM(Agr_Hrs) AS Hrs_Agr,
          SUM(TE_TotalCost) AS Project_TC, 
          Project_Number,
          REC_ID,
          Full_Name
        FROM
         (
          SELECT
          Rec_ID,
          Full_Name,
          Project_Number,
            SUM(VT_Hrs_Agr) AS Agr_Hrs, 
            SUM(Line_TC) AS TE_TotalCost, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN Billing_Type = 'B' THEN (TE_Hrs_Inv) ELSE 0 END) AS Hrs_B,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Billing_Type = 'NB' THEN (TE_Hrs_Inv) ELSE 0 END) AS Hrs_NB, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN Billing_Type = 'NC' THEN (TE_Hrs_Inv) ELSE 0 END) AS Hrs_NC
        FROM
         (
          SELECT
          VT_Hrs_Cost,
          TE_Hrs_Inv,
          Line_TC,
          VT_Hrs_B,
          VT_Hrs_NB, 
          VT_Hrs_Agr,
          Project_Number,
          Rec_ID,
          Full_Name,
          Billing_Type, 
          Work_Role
        FROM
         (
          SELECT
          v_rpt_Time.Hourly_Cost AS VT_Hrs_Cost, 
          Time_Entry.Hours_Invoiced AS TE_Hrs_Inv, 
          v_rpt_Time.Hourly_Cost * Time_Entry.Hours_Invoiced AS Line_TC,
          v_rpt_Time.Billable_Hrs AS VT_Hrs_B, 
          v_rpt_Time.NonBillable_Hrs AS VT_Hrs_NB, 
          v_rpt_Time.AgrHrsCovered AS VT_Hrs_Agr, 
          Time_Entry.PM_Project_RecID AS Project_Number, 
          v_rpt_Time.member_recid AS Rec_ID, 
          v_rpt_Time.first_name + ' ' + v_rpt_Time.last_name AS Full_Name,
          v_rpt_Time.option_id AS Billing_Type, 
          v_rpt_Time.work_role AS Work_Role
        FROM
        Time_Entry
            INNER JOIN
            v_rpt_Time
            ON 
            Time_Entry.Time_RecID = v_rpt_Time.Time_RecID
            ) 
            AS Project_Hrs
            )
            AS Project_Hrs_Sorted
             GROUP BY
             Project_Number,
             Billing_Type,
             TE_Hrs_Inv,
             VT_Hrs_Agr,
             Rec_ID,
             Full_Name
             ) 
             AS Project_Cost
              GROUP BY 
               Project_Number,
               Rec_ID,
               Full_Name
               )
               AS Project_Totals
               GROUP BY
               Project_Number
               )
               AS B
               )
               AS Table_B
               ON
               Table_A.Project_Number = Table_B.Project_Number
               ) AS PPRS,
/*  Section that creates the Column to Row using a CROSS APPLY and STUFF Command with XML */ 
        (
        SELECT
        Project_Number, 
        PeopleNRole
        FROM
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
        Base.PeopleNrole,
        p1.Project_Number
        FROM
        ( 
         SELECT DISTINCT     
            Time_Entry10.PM_Project_RecID AS Project_Number,
            (v_rpt_Time10.first_name + ' ' + v_rpt_Time10.last_name /* + ' ' + member10.Role_id Removes the SE from the Name*/) AS PeopleNrole,
            Member10.Role_ID AS RoleID
        FROM
        Time_Entry AS Time_Entry10
        INNER JOIN
        v_rpt_Time AS v_rpt_Time10
        ON
        Time_Entry10.Time_RecID = v_rpt_Time10.Time_RecID
        INNER JOIN
        Member AS Member10
        ON
        v_rpt_Time10.member_recid = Member10.Member_RecID AND Member10.Role_ID = 'SE'
        --order by Time_Entry10.Hours_Bill desc
        )
        AS P1

        CROSS APPLY
        (
         SELECT
             STUFF
             (
              (
               SELECT ', ' + PeopleNrole
                FROM
                (
                 SELECT DISTINCT    
                 Time_Entry11.PM_Project_RecID AS Project_Number,
                (v_rpt_Time11.first_name + ' ' + v_rpt_Time11.last_name/* + ' ' + member11.Role_id Removes the SE from the Name*/ ) AS PeopleNrole,
                Member11.Role_ID
                AS
                RoleID
                FROM
                Time_Entry
                AS
                Time_Entry11
                INNER JOIN 
                v_rpt_Time AS v_rpt_Time11
                ON
                Time_Entry11.Time_RecID = v_rpt_Time11.Time_RecID
                INNER JOIN
                Member AS Member11
                ON
                v_rpt_Time11.member_recid = Member11.Member_RecID AND Member11.Role_ID = 'SE'
                --order by Time_Entry11.Hours_Bill desc
                )
                AS
                P2
                WHERE
                p2.Project_Number = P1.Project_Number
                ORDER BY
                Time_Entry.Hours_Bill
                FOR
                XML
                PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')) Base(PeopleNRole))
                AS PeopleLink
                )
                AS pl2
                WHERE
                PPRS.PN_A = PL2.Project_Number
                )
                AS PPRS2
                INNER JOIN
                (
                  SELECT 
                  Opportunity_RecID,
                  AM,
                  DA,
                  PM
                FROM 
                (
                SELECT
                 N.Opportunity_RecID,
                 Member_1.First_Name + ' ' + Member_1.Last_Name AS AM,
                 Member_2.First_Name + ' ' + Member_2.Last_Name AS DA, 
                 Member_3.First_Name + ' ' + Member_3.Last_Name AS PM
                FROM 
                Member AS Member_1
                INNER JOIN
                (
                 SELECT DISTINCT
                 v_rpt_Opportunity3.Opportunity_RecID,
                 v_rpt_Opportunity3.Sales_Rep1,
                 v_rpt_Opportunity3.Sales_Rep2,
                 PM_Project3.Member_ID
                 FROM 
                  v_rpt_Opportunity AS v_rpt_Opportunity3
                  INNER JOIN
                  PM_Project AS PM_Project3
                  ON 
                  v_rpt_Opportunity3.Opportunity_RecID = PM_Project3.Opportunity_RecID
                  ) AS N
                  ON 
                  Member_1.Member_ID = N.Sales_Rep1
                  INNER JOIN
                  Member AS Member_2
                  ON
                  N.Sales_Rep2 = Member_2.Member_ID
                  INNER JOIN
                  Member AS Member_3
                  ON
                  N.Member_ID = Member_3.Member_ID
                  )
                  AS AMDA
                  )
                  AS AMDA2
                  ON 
                  PPRS2.OPP_RECID = AMDA2.Opportunity_RecID
                  )
                  AS PPRS_pt1
                    WHERE
                    Date_Closed_UTC BETWEEN @Startdate AND @EndDate
                    AND 
                                        Location <> 'AOSCloud'
                    /* (Location IN(@Division))
                    AND Per Leslie 8/14/2013 want all divisions listed 
                    (Project_Practice =   IN (@Practice)*/

                    ORDER BY PN_B
```

I have committed out kind of where I think I needed to edit the query timeentry10 and timeentry11 but I cant do this because order by clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries and common table expressions, unless top, offset,or for xml is also specified... So what I did was try to do time_entry.hours_bill desc but it is telling me that I do not have access to the time_entry at that position. What they had before is order by roleid before the for xml. this really has me thrown off because I feel it is over complicated. Any help with this would be great. I also would not be opposed to take the peoplenrole add another column and just get the person with the most hours and add it to the report saying SE with most hours for the business.

the section that gets the peoplenrole is this

```
*   Section that creates the Column to Row using a CROSS APPLY and STUFF Command with XML */ 
        (
        SELECT
        Project_Number, 
        PeopleNRole
        FROM
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
        Base.PeopleNrole,
        p1.Project_Number
        FROM
        ( 
         SELECT DISTINCT     
            Time_Entry10.PM_Project_RecID AS Project_Number,
            (v_rpt_Time10.first_name + ' ' + v_rpt_Time10.last_name /* + ' ' + member10.Role_id Removes the SE from the Name*/) AS PeopleNrole,
            Member10.Role_ID AS RoleID
        FROM
        Time_Entry AS Time_Entry10
        INNER JOIN
        v_rpt_Time AS v_rpt_Time10
        ON
        Time_Entry10.Time_RecID = v_rpt_Time10.Time_RecID
        INNER JOIN
        Member AS Member10
        ON
        v_rpt_Time10.member_recid = Member10.Member_RecID AND Member10.Role_ID = 'SE'
        --order by Time_Entry10.Hours_Bill desc
        )
        AS P1

        CROSS APPLY
        (
         SELECT
             STUFF
             (
              (
               SELECT ', ' + PeopleNrole
                FROM
                (
                 SELECT DISTINCT    
                 Time_Entry11.PM_Project_RecID AS Project_Number,
                (v_rpt_Time11.first_name + ' ' + v_rpt_Time11.last_name/* + ' ' + member11.Role_id Removes the SE from the Name*/ ) AS PeopleNrole,
                Member11.Role_ID
                AS
                RoleID
                FROM
                Time_Entry
                AS
                Time_Entry11
                INNER JOIN 
                v_rpt_Time AS v_rpt_Time11
                ON
                Time_Entry11.Time_RecID = v_rpt_Time11.Time_RecID
                INNER JOIN
                Member AS Member11
                ON
                v_rpt_Time11.member_recid = Member11.Member_RecID AND Member11.Role_ID = 'SE'
                --order by Time_Entry11.Hours_Bill desc
                )
                AS
                P2
                WHERE
                p2.Project_Number = P1.Project_Number
                ORDER BY
                RoleID
                FOR
                XML
                PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')) Base(PeopleNRole))
                AS PeopleLink
                )
                AS pl2
                WHERE
                PPRS.PN_A = PL2.Project_Number
                )
```

here is a pic of the data [image]

Comment: good luck. if you aren't able to intepret this (and you have the db with the data in it to look at, we don't) it really isn't going to be likely that we will understand your data model enough to propose a solution. I don't see how that query would list engineers at all. Looks to me like you need a separate query for that,

Comment: hey just updated the question. i can read it somewhat, but to me this is overboard and wish I had access to whomever wrote it. The section I am mostly interested in is that people in row xml binding. Thanks for even looking at it though I appreciate it

Comment: I recommend you switch out the subqueries for CTEs.  It will help you better correlate the selected source (FROM) with the filter (WHERE) and joins (ON).

Answer (score 0):

So quick and dirty I found an SSRS report obviously this same person did that calculated these hours like this

```
SELECT  F_Name, L_Name, Total_TE_Hours_Actual, project_id
FROM (SELECT SUM(TE_Part2.TE_Hours_Actual) AS Total_TE_Hours_Actual, Member.First_Name AS F_Name, Member.Last_Name AS L_Name, TE_Part2.PM_Project_RecID as project_id
FROM            
(SELECT TE_Hours_Actual, PM_Project_RecID, Rec_ID
FROM            
(SELECT v_rpt_Time.Hourly_Cost AS TE_Hourly_Cost, v_rpt_Time.hours_actual AS TE_Hours_Actual, Time_Entry.PM_Project_RecID, v_rpt_Time.NonBillable_Hrs AS TE_Hours_Non_Billable, v_rpt_Time.member_recid AS Rec_ID
FROM Time_Entry 
INNER JOIN v_rpt_Time ON Time_Entry.Time_RecID = v_rpt_Time.Time_RecID
) AS TE_Part1) AS TE_Part2 
INNER JOIN Member ON TE_Part2.Rec_ID = Member.Member_RecID
GROUP BY TE_Part2.Rec_ID, Member.First_Name, Member.Last_Name, TE_Part2.PM_Project_RecID) AS TE_Part3
```

so I put this to a CTE like this

```
with time_CTE(F_Name, L_Name, Total_TE_Hours_Actual, project_id) as (
SELECT  F_Name, L_Name, Total_TE_Hours_Actual, project_id
FROM (SELECT SUM(TE_Part2.TE_Hours_Actual) AS Total_TE_Hours_Actual, Member.First_Name AS F_Name, Member.Last_Name AS L_Name, TE_Part2.PM_Project_RecID as project_id
FROM            
(SELECT TE_Hours_Actual, PM_Project_RecID, Rec_ID
FROM            
(SELECT v_rpt_Time.Hourly_Cost AS TE_Hourly_Cost, v_rpt_Time.hours_actual AS TE_Hours_Actual, Time_Entry.PM_Project_RecID, v_rpt_Time.NonBillable_Hrs AS TE_Hours_Non_Billable, v_rpt_Time.member_recid AS Rec_ID
FROM Time_Entry 
INNER JOIN v_rpt_Time ON Time_Entry.Time_RecID = v_rpt_Time.Time_RecID
) AS TE_Part1) AS TE_Part2 
INNER JOIN Member ON TE_Part2.Rec_ID = Member.Member_RecID
GROUP BY TE_Part2.Rec_ID, Member.First_Name, Member.Last_Name, TE_Part2.PM_Project_RecID) AS TE_Part3)
select top 1 f_name + ' ' + l_name as Name, total_TE_Hours_Actual, project_id from time_CTE
where project_id is not null
order by Total_TE_Hours_Actual desc;
```

I made a new column in my ssrs that said top SE then I did a lookup like this

```
=lookup (Fields!PN_A.value, Fields!project_id.value, Fields!Name.value, "SETime")
```

so this satisfied the business user, but I am taking the advice I got here and breaking that main query up into CTEs that thing is way to ugly